# Android system to identify a particular uri and open a specific application

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible for the Android system to identify a particular uri and open a specific application?

Example email a person a uri that starts with test://testing. When the user clicks on it, it will open my application.

Is it possible? Not sure how to implement this. I tried looking at Broadcast receiver. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

I used it to detect SMS but how to get it to recognize customised links etc?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an Intent filter in your manifest that will tell the system "I can open such links".

Something like :

```
<activity android:name=".myActivity">
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <!-- for test://... use "test" as sheme:  -->
        <data android:scheme="test" />

        <!-- you can also use some other parameters:  -->
        <data android:host="my.hostname.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What you are looking for is IntentFilter,  [learn more about it here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

i think 'scheme' can do that thing.

you can click a custom url in any other app. and open it with your app.

there are some page useful.

[introduce](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

[a question like yours](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120393/custom-url-scheme---iphone--android)